# how to show admob interstitial on app exit

Tags: android, admob, back-button

how to show ad mob interstitial ad on app exit.
I tried it using onBackPressed() method but getting errors
Code for interstitial ad

```
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, "AD_ID");


    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();


    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);


    interstitial.setAdListener(this);
  }
    @Override
      public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {

        if (ad == interstitial) {
          interstitial.show();
        }

    }
```

What is the correct way to do it.

Comment: I don't recommend you doing this. Google is really cracking down on obtrusive ads and the developer docs explicitly say not to block an exit of the app. By doing this you set yourself up for app suspension. Instead I recommend that you show the ad in key points in your app

Comment: Actually when the ad loads during the app then the activity starts from beginning, i.e. all the user action starts from beginning. any way to avoid that. My app uses ondraw() method and when the interstitial shows any time then the user has to start from scratch...
any help on this

Comment: @RSenApps My understanding of that was that if the user clicks home the app exits, full stop. Within the app you press the back button for a variety of things (to go from game to menu for example) so is this particular back press (the one thats caught for an interstitial show) actually special? I ask because onExit is when the user is most likely to actually want to see an ad (for something else to do) and least likely to be annoyed by it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't attempt to show an Ad on app exit, as RSenApps says show it at a key point in your app instead.

If your problem is that when the interstitial shows it causes the views to be redrawn on your Activity, then you need to persist or cache the drawing state of your Activity so that previous state can be quickly redrawn as needed.

Answer (score 7):

I just had a nice talk with an employee at Admob about how to increase my ad revenue. And his recommendation was to add an interstitial when the players exit my game apps. I did not read through all the terms and conditions but I do believe that the Admob official knows the standard regulations and would not recommend this behavior if it was not allowed.

Technically I am going to implement it in this way:

1) Catch when the user clicks on my exit button or hits the back button on the main screen

2) Check if an interstitial is loaded and ready to be displayed

-> 3a) if it is not ready, i let the user quit without delay

-> 3b) if it is ready, I show the interstitial and listen to it being closed, when it is closed, I exit the app automatically

Comment: just a heads up, I had interstitial ads setup like yours but received an email from admob that I cannot do that. I am pasting their email content as an answer below.

Comment: thanks @Thupten, I am getting the feeling that Admob does not know what it wants, I talked to two seperate Admob officials that told me, that my interstitials were fine (one of them did not know exactly and had to check with other colleagues before telling me it was ok) but I received a warning anyways... but they did not tell me which ad was the problem, so I am really confused about the admob rules

Comment: @Thupten Where is the email? You said you were pasting it

Comment: @erdomester,  its pasted in my answer. it seems it not below this answer but somewhere above it.

Comment: @BjörnKechel You are more than 100% correct and same situation happened with my clients as well. When I talked to admob employee, even he sent me an email regarding it - how to increase revenue with exit ad, but when I read some articles about it, its policy violation. and when I Implemented it, i get the same email as well.

Comment: @Björn Kechel, would you tell us at last how you deal with this issue?

Comment: I removed the functionality from my app because it causes problems with google. I guess not everybody there knows the exact rules so I prefer to be cautious now.

Answer (score 3):

Do not place your ads at the exit of the app as it goes against admob policy.

[image: This is not allowed as per admob policy]

[Please checkout this link](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en)

Answer (score 2):

I had interstitial ad just before user exit the app. This is excerpts of email that I received from admob. After receiving this email, I removed the interstitial ads completely and resubmitted the app.

> ### Violation explanation
>
> LAYOUT ENCOURAGES ACCIDENTAL CLICKS - INTERSTITIAL ADS: Publishers are not permitted to encourage users to click AdMob interstitial ads in any way. This includes any implementation that may encourage accidental clicks, such as placing an interstitial ad in a way that prevents viewing the app’s core content or placing an interstitial ad in a way that interferes with navigating or interacting with the app’s core content and functionality.
>
> Please review how you’ve implemented interstitial ads and be mindful of the following common examples of non-compliant implementations:
>
> - Interstitial ads that appear before the app has opened or after the app has closed.
> - Interstitial ads that are triggered after a user closes another interstitial ad.
> - Interstitial ads loading unexpectedly while a user is viewing the app’s content. Remember to only serve interstitials between pages of content.
> - Interstitial ads that trigger after every user click.
> - Interstitial ads that appear during periods of game play or heavy user interaction.
>
> For more information about our policies and tips for how to comply please read the following:
>
> AdMob ad placement policy
> AdMob interstitial ad guidance
>
> Action required: Check account for compliance
> While ad serving has been disabled to the above app, your AdMob account remains active. We suggest that you take the time to review the rest of your applications to ensure that they’re in compliance with our policies, and to monitor your apps accordingly to reduce the likelihood of future policy emails from us. Additionally, please note that our team reserves the right to disable accounts at any time if we continue to see violations occurring.

Comment: The way I understand this ruling, and that is how an admob official told me as well, is that an interstitial has to come immediately when exiting, it cannot pop up after some delay after the app has closed. But it seems that within Admob they cannot decide how to apply this rule correctly. To be on the safe side you should simply not use an interstitial on app exit.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but.. I' ll reply for others this is my code.

This is one way, detect when user press Back Button and show a dialog with a positive and negative and if they press "Yes" call your interstitial method.

Greetens

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);
        alert.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        alert.setMessage(R.string.quit);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int whichButton) {
                                                //call your method here then finish activity;

                        interstitial();

                        finish();
                    }



                });

    alert.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
    alert.show();
    return true;
}

return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

Comment: Did you actually test your code? You are finishing the activity immediately after showing the interstitial.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Log.d(TAG, "onBackPressed Called");
   displayInterstitial();

   finish();

}
```